# Does resolution of singularities always factor through normalization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be an integral scheme and let $\tilde{X}$ denote its normalization.  Is it always true that any resolution of singularities $X' \to X$ factors through the normalization map $\tilde{X} \to X$?  If yes, why?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because the normalisation satisfies the following universal property:

if $Z$ is normal and integral, and $f: Z \rightarrow X$ is dominant, then $f$ factors uniquely through the normalisation $\nu: \tilde{X} \rightarrow X$.

Apply this with $Z=X'$, which is nonsingular, hence normal.

See Hartshorne II.3 for details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Another (unrelated) question: is it true that the normalization map $\tilde{X} \to X$ a smooth morphism?

Comment: @user126952 You shouldn't ask two questions in the same thread. The answer is almost never. In fact, a normalization map is flat implies it's an isomorphism (under mild assumptions).